# Im writing my first Gui game and am running into some widget issues

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm writing a text game where you have to enter as many of the randomly generated (from a file) words in 60 seconds. I currently have a working timer but my entry widget won't do anything.
I should be able to press enter on my entry widget and if the word within is equal to the generated word the score goes up. The box should also be cleared however it doesn't do that either.

```
def game(*args):
    if timer == 60: # Starts the timer and calls the words function
        countdown()
    words()


def words():
    global score
    global timer

    if timer > 0:
        entry.focus_set()  # Activate the entry box
        word = str(random.choice(word_list[0]))
        word_label.config(text=word)
        if entry.get().lower() == word.lower():
            score += 1
            entry.delete(0, 9999999)
    if timer == 0:
        results(score)


def countdown():
    global timer

    if timer > 0:
        timer -= 1
        # Update the time left label
        time_label.config(text="Time left: " + str(timer))

        # Run the function again after 1 second
        time_label.after(1000, countdown)
```

These are the main functions involved.

```
# Gui
root = Tk()
root.title("Text Typers")

# Create the top frame
top_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Menu:")
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

# Play button
play_button = ttk.Button(top_frame, text="Play", command=game)
play_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# Timer
time_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Time left: " + str(timer))
time_label.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# Entry function
entry = ttk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=8, column=0)


# Word label
word_label = ttk.Label(root, font=20)
word_label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

This is all the relevant GUI code. Has something gone over my head? 
Edit: After more testing it seems that the code doesn't even run to the 'if entry' part is it because theres the timer function running and preventing the words function to function properly?

Comment: You have indentation errors, starting at `if timer ...`

Comment: That was a mistake in copying it one here, the code itself doesn't have any indentation error

Comment: [Edit] your question and fix it! ***press enter***: Read up on [Events and Bindings - `<Return>`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check the word when you press enter, you may want to add a key listen event, this is how I would do it:

```
def key_press(event):
     #here you would put your function for checking the word
     print "key_press", repr(event.char)
```

Then, on your root:

```
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.bind("<KeyRelease-enter>", key_press)
frame.pack
```

Comment: What does the event parameter do? Also the Keysm gave me trouble, I am on python 3.